# Open Lite Speed + Elementor not save changes

Tags: caching, browser-cache, elementor, openlitespeed

since i've jumped from apache to open lite speed and started to use OLS cache i have problem with Elementor.
I'm creating something in elementor (can be block, page, post... doesn't matter what) and save it (lets call it v.1). All works fine.
When i want to change something, i'm editing it in Elementor, make some changes (lets call it v.2), save it and ... in front page i see no changes. So i'm reload (F5 or CRTL + F5) and i see page without changes (v.1).
I'm cleaning cache, browser - without success.
I'm taking a look in elementor page history and i see record with my changes (v.2). I click on it, restore changes and i see (v.2), so i save it.
On front page i can see v.2 but on Elementor after F5 / CTRL + F5 i still see v.1.

I suppose that somehow OLS cache is caching my editable pages/posts in backend and once it is cached it won't show any changes. But it should works when i'm cleaning cache...
Did you had any experience with it?

-- update

I see, that when i enable checkPublicCache (set to 1) the problem with Elementor occur:

When is disabled (set to 0) Elementor works fine.
I wonder why - Admin panel shouldn't be cached so much, it's rather private cache not public...

serve stale is off
Cleaning cache from wordpress not work, even disable cache from OLS plugin doesn't works.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**:
it doesn't matter to the checkPrivateCache nor checkPublicCache. It's because you set the **enableCache** to `On` which will cache everything.

enableCache:

- setting enables or disables the public cache. (Set to 1 to enable. Set to 0 to disable.) If both public and private cache are enabled, OpenLiteSpeed will save to the private cache first.

**Solution**:

I'd recommend you set the cache module back to default value:

```
checkPrivateCache   1
checkPublicCache    1
maxCacheObjSize     10000000
maxStaleAge         200
qsCache             1
reqCookieCache      1
respCookieCache     1
ignoreReqCacheCtrl  1
ignoreRespCacheCtrl 0

enableCache         0
expireInSeconds     3600
enablePrivateCache  0
privateExpireInSeconds 3600
```

So the WordPress site will rely on the LSCache plugin to cache things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure in plugin -> Cache -> Purge -> `serve stale` was OFF
2. run in SSH command `rm -rf /usr/local/lsws/tmpdata/*` to clean all caches
3. if you have enable UCSS and CCSS , as if you see `purge CCSS` and `purge UCSS` in drop down menu , purge them both

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to fix that go to CSS Settings --> disable Generate UCSS and disable CCSS per URL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).